# Internal Server Error 500; trying to Post using okhttp3 to django rest framework

Tags: android, django-rest-framework

I have a working backend url that I can browse and post requests with different endpoints with no issues. It is developed by django rest framework and is served using Nginx.

when I send a post request as follows:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, new Gson().toJson(obj));

Request post_request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url_str)
        .post(body)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "")
        .build();

client.newCall(post_request).enqueue(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {


        } else {

        }
    }
```

I really dont think there is anything wrong in my backend side, as I said it is working fine and I can do all CRUDS with different endpoint in internet browsers, in different devises and machines. 
I was wondering if any one might know what could be the issue,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

turned out that I should not use "Authorization", so the correct request would be:

```
Request post_request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url_str)
        .post(body)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "")
        .build();
```